# Hide panel for fullscreen applications

Tags: panel, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-panel, fullscreen

I use Ubuntu 20.10.

When I play a Steam game full screen, the panel (the top bar) still shows up and goes over the application, as well as the window list from [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/).

How can I hide them in fullscreen applications?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

The problem was that the game was not running in true "fullscreen" mode, although it declared so.

Workaround was: go to game settings, set "windowed mode", maximize the window, return to settings and set "fullscreen mode".

Now the game should run in proper fullscreen mode, covering all the screen